# Numerical Integral in MatLab using integral command

Tags: matlab, math

I am trying to compute the value of this integral using Matlab
[image]

Here the other parameters have been defined or computed in the earlier part of the program as follows

```
N = 2;
sigma = [0.01 0.1];
l = [15];
meu = 4*pi*10^(-7);
f = logspace ( 1, 6, 500);
w=2*pi.*f;
for j = 1 : length(f)
q2(j)= sqrt(sqrt(-1)*2*pi*f(j)*meu*sigma(2));
q1(j)= sqrt(sqrt(-1)*2*pi*f(j)*meu*sigma(1));
C2(j)= 1/(q2(j));
C1(j)= (q1(j)*C2(j) + tanh(q1(j)*l))/(q1(j)*(1+q1(j)*C2(j)*tanh(q1(j)*l)));
Z(j) = sqrt(-1)*2*pi*f(j)*C1(j);
Apprho(j) = meu*(1/(2*pi*f(j))*(abs(Z(j))^2));
Phi(j) = atan(imag(Z(j))/real(Z(j)));
end

%integration part
c1=w./(2*pi);
rho0=1;
fun = @(x) log(Apprho(x)/rho0)/(x.^2-w^2);
c2= integral(fun,0,Inf);
phin=pi/4-c1.*c2;
```

I am getting an error like this
[image]

could anyone help and tell me where i am going wrong.thanks in advance

Comment: You create `Apphro` in the `for` loop as an array, but then you use it in the integration as a function.

Comment: my objective is to calculate the integral part-to do this I need to define Apprho function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `Apprho` in a separate *.m function file, instead of storing it in an array:

```
function [ result ] = Apprho(x)
%
% Calculate f and Z based on input argument x
%
% ...
%
meu = 4*pi*10^(-7);
result = meu*(1/(2*pi*f)*(abs(Z)^2));
end
```

How you calculate f and Z is up to you.

MATLAB's `integral` works by calling the function (in this case, `Apprho`) repeatedly at many different `x` values.  The `x` values called by `integral` don't necessarily correspond to the `1: length(f)` values used in your original code, which is why you received errors.